# jq returns an array of empty values

Tags: json, jq

I have an huge json file (around 7GB) with multiple elements, let's call it `data.json`. Each element looks like this:

```json
{
  "aggregation_bits": "0xf7fffffffffffdfffffffffffffdfffffffffffffffffffffff7fffffffffffffff7ff",
  "data": {
    "slot": "6436981",
    "index": "8",
    "beacon_block_root": "0xf8afce2fc26df10061d641633a7256cf47ffa8793771ae83e190e72bf2c5886e",
    "source": {
      "epoch": "201154",
      "root": "0x694231a8135b3f546a6fe483ba6b467c686592f6d627aaf06b56ffbd78d75f63"
    },
    "target": {
      "epoch": "201155",
      "root": "0x2fc0d9f58cda026678d98f010fec13d202eec4ec9ae4dbd57878413a75fe22d7"
    }
  },
  "signature": "0xadb0d576ee418e37017f423e77622ce85bdb741d0e984e78df3a250c172fc67c6c7ec94e4802d6323aee8f62b7df218300f42010fe673ed85f4e06d1361336474ecfb4db39aa2bc31b31bf6fbe52c7bff769f024faa5ba3554d5ea02fe9663c3",
  "arrival": 1684067808365
}
```

What I want to do is use `jq` scripting to select all elements that contain slot with a certain value and save them in a separate json file, let's call it `data_for_slot.json`

Let's assume I want all elements where `slot = 6436990`. For this purpose, I used:

```
jq -c '[select(.data.slot == "6436990")]' data.json > data_for_slot.json
```

After running for some time, it returned `data_for_slot.json`, but when I opened it to inspect, what I got was:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
...
```

I know for a fact that `slot = 6436990` exists in some of the elements, so I was expecting an array of such elements, but got this instead. I don't understand why is it returning results like this, while not throwing any error.

I am very new to `jq` scripting, and I would appreciate if anyone could tell me what am I doing wrong and what is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: Note that JSON uses double quotes `"` for strings, not single quotes `'`.

Comment: As in, select(.data.slot == "6436990")?

Comment: As in `{"aggregation_bits": "0xf7ffff …", …}`

Comment: Please follow the [mre] guidelines as much as possible. A small but complete and telling sample input would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

The jq filter `[select(.data.slot == "6436990")]` will create an array `[…]` for each input item. As you are filtering out (most of) the input items using `select(…)`, you get a stream of (mostly) empty arrays.

Drop the array brackets (just use `select(…)`) and there will be no output for input items not matching.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This, however, returns an entirely empty file.

Comment: @ПавелЗорановичКеркезов Then, I assume, your input document is not a stream of objects (as suggested by your sample). Maybe it is an array of objects. What are the first characters of the entire input file?

Comment: @ПавелЗорановичКеркезов Here are some more caveats regarding "I know for a fact that slot = 6436990 exists": Maybe those item(s) have a field `"slot": 6436990` (with the value being a number), which structurally differs from your sample data where `"slot": "6436981"` carries a string (and your `select(…)` filter also tries to match a string). In this case, just drop the all the quotes around numbers. Another reason could be that there is a matching `.slot` but not under `.data` (as it is in your sample data and your sample filter). Can you check and/or post some details regarding these issues?